# Why p-values are not significant even though AIC values improved a lot in model selection using GAM mix modelling and beta regression

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, beta-distribution, mgcv

Dear StatExchange community,

I am studying disease progression in plant leaves and I am trying to estimate differences between a wild-type and a mutant plant. To achieve this I am using the proportion of healthy pixels in images of plant leaves. Due the type of data I decided to analyze it using gam modeling and beta regression to determinate if the plant genotype has an impact in the disease progression.

So I created two models, one base model with my response variable **(size)** as a function of hours post infection **(hpi)**. I considered **hpi** and **leaf_id** as random factors.

```
require(mgcv)    
m0 = gam(size ~ s(hpi, k = 4) + s(hpi, leaf_id, bs = "re"), data = data, family = "betar")
m1 = gam(size ~ s(hpi, by = genotype, k = 4) + s(hpi, leaf_id, bs = "re") + genotype, data = data, family = "betar")
```

All good until here, except when I tested the goodness of fit I did not get any significant p-values even though AIC value improved a lot.

```
anova(m0, m1, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: size ~ s(hpi, k = 4) + s(hpi, leaf_id, bs = "re")
Model 2: size ~ s(hpi, by = genotype, k = 4) + s(hpi, leaf_id, bs = "re") + 
    genotype
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev    Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1    92.456     95.862                        
2    89.541     92.029 2.915   3.8333   0.2678
AIC(m0)
[1] -433.6965
AIC(m1)
[1] -451.1168
```

Do you think there is really not difference between the genotypes or maybe it is incorrect to use anova when one use beta regression?

**Here the data I used to fit the models and the fitted model:**

```
leaf_id hpi genotype    size
1_A_01  0   Wild-type   0.999409681
1_A_01  24  Wild-type   0.965263468
1_A_01  48  Wild-type   0.877621373
1_A_01  72  Wild-type   0.527381631
1_A_01  96  Wild-type   0.499122294
1_A_02  0   Wild-type   0.99834779
1_A_02  24  Wild-type   0.9128
1_A_02  48  Wild-type   0.77067519
1_A_02  72  Wild-type   0.419811321
1_A_02  96  Wild-type   0.359519038
1_A_03  0   Wild-type   0.998700455
1_A_03  24  Wild-type   0.941766419
1_A_03  48  Wild-type   0.452631579
1_A_03  72  Wild-type   0.200547778
1_A_03  96  Wild-type   0.119721038
1_A_04  0   Wild-type   0.998331745
1_A_04  24  Wild-type   0.950153555
1_A_04  48  Wild-type   0.7578354
1_A_04  72  Wild-type   0.387827632
1_A_04  96  Wild-type   0.305003427
1_A_05  0   Wild-type   0.994119377
1_A_05  24  Wild-type   0.963669391
1_A_05  48  Wild-type   0.851896813
1_A_05  72  Wild-type   0.618860511
1_A_05  96  Wild-type   0.557251908
1_A_06  0   Wild-type   0.994492044
1_A_06  24  Wild-type   0.93710493
1_A_06  48  Wild-type   0.689569019
1_A_06  72  Wild-type   0.384522734
1_A_06  96  Wild-type   0.309379968
1_A_07  0   Wild-type   0.989961925
1_A_07  24  Wild-type   0.949456174
1_A_07  48  Wild-type   0.809640774
1_A_07  72  Wild-type   0.475455387
1_A_07  96  Wild-type   0.456692913
1_A_08  0   Wild-type   0.979972845
1_A_08  24  Wild-type   0.957887917
1_A_08  48  Wild-type   0.684027778
1_A_08  72  Wild-type   0.472561932
1_A_08  96  Wild-type   0.438386385
1_A_09  0   Wild-type   0.971879106
1_A_09  24  Wild-type   0.956667526
1_A_09  48  Wild-type   0.487238387
1_A_09  72  Wild-type   0.231512071
1_A_09  96  Wild-type   0.179140127
1_A_10  0   Wild-type   0.962017804
1_A_10  24  Wild-type   0.950415592
1_A_10  48  Wild-type   0.607827039
1_A_10  72  Wild-type   0.46189693
1_A_10  96  Wild-type   0.443232662
1_A_11  0   Wild-type   0.968882603
1_A_11  24  Wild-type   0.959830867
1_A_11  48  Wild-type   0.952662722
1_A_11  72  Wild-type   0.88
1_A_11  96  Wild-type   0.764691358
1_A_12  0   Wild-type   0.965517241
1_A_12  24  Wild-type   0.880882353
1_A_12  48  Wild-type   0.313450857
1_A_12  72  Wild-type   0.190072924
1_A_12  96  Wild-type   0.162589928
1_B_01  0   mutant  0.983951856
1_B_01  24  mutant  0.924170616
1_B_01  48  mutant  0.973675964
1_B_01  72  mutant  0.974430068
1_B_01  96  mutant  0.927825261
1_B_02  0   mutant  0.972856418
1_B_02  24  mutant  0.933898305
1_B_02  48  mutant  0.944825953
1_B_02  72  mutant  0.95001179
1_B_02  96  mutant  0.919257652
1_B_03  0   mutant  0.927007299
1_B_03  24  mutant  0.921632653
1_B_03  48  mutant  0.953442879
1_B_03  72  mutant  0.951305025
1_B_03  96  mutant  0.920571882
1_B_04  0   mutant  0.954979129
1_B_04  24  mutant  0.936366254
1_B_04  48  mutant  0.888105727
1_B_04  72  mutant  0.810614525
1_B_04  96  mutant  0.770698849
1_B_05  0   mutant  0.941514075
1_B_05  24  mutant  0.854272864
1_B_05  48  mutant  0.45239486
1_B_05  72  mutant  0.303134886
1_B_05  96  mutant  0.25814978
1_B_06  0   mutant  0.964714389
1_B_06  24  mutant  0.971969069
1_B_06  48  mutant  0.962336245
1_B_06  72  mutant  0.967693971
1_B_06  96  mutant  0.965025374
1_B_07  0   mutant  0.984585742
1_B_07  24  mutant  0.970041841
1_B_07  48  mutant  0.976478275
1_B_07  72  mutant  0.977969974
1_B_07  96  mutant  0.960810143
1_B_08  0   mutant  0.993533584
1_B_08  24  mutant  0.957139955
1_B_08  48  mutant  0.938698833
1_B_08  72  mutant  0.873435055
1_B_08  96  mutant  0.838285145
1_B_09  0   mutant  0.974298565
1_B_09  24  mutant  0.956712673
1_B_09  48  mutant  0.967297408
1_B_09  72  mutant  0.965707287
1_B_09  96  mutant  0.918210198
1_B_10  0   mutant  0.997560976
1_B_10  24  mutant  0.983135392
1_B_10  48  mutant  0.977892756
1_B_10  72  mutant  0.948681397
1_B_10  96  mutant  0.932846715
1_B_11  0   mutant  0.965979637
1_B_11  24  mutant  0.936755047
1_B_11  48  mutant  0.723308979
1_B_11  72  mutant  0.334980005
1_B_11  96  mutant  0.245347698
1_B_12  0   mutant  0.989107764
1_B_12  24  mutant  0.973660714
1_B_12  48  mutant  0.990679095
1_B_12  72  mutant  0.988659106
1_B_12  96  mutant  0.978579481
```

[image: Fitted model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the p-values from the multi-model form of `anova.gam()`. Reading `?anova.gam` Simon gives plenty of warnings about using this, although in the direction opposite to what you see here.

Instead I'd use `AIC()` as you did already. I would also perhaps compute the differences between the two smooths, and perhaps do a different decomposition but with an ordered `genotype`:

```
## pseudo code
ogenotype <- as.ordered(genotype)
m1 <- gam(size ~ s(hpi) + s(hpi, by = ogenotype, k = 4) +
            s(hpi, leaf_id, bs = "re") + ogenotype,
          data = data, family = "betar")
```

This decomposition will fit a smooth (`s(hpi)`) for the reference level and a "difference" term relative to the reference level for each other level. This is like the default contrasts in `lm()` where the intercept is the reference level and the model contains other terms that are the difference between the levels and the reference level.

Then `summary(m1)` will give you a test directly for a difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Gavin, indeed the help file suggest not to use p-values for gams model selection. I will stick to AIC then, I tried the second approach you suggested, but apparently I ran out of degrees of freedom. I will try to simulate some data with a higher n. I will declare your answer as definitive. Many thanks for you advice :)